# Which variables should be list, which should be attributes?

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to find a reference or advice as to which variables in an object should be stored as a list and which should be stored as attributes. It appears that on many occasions, both are used simultaneously.

Are list generally the main variables involved in the computation while attributes are mostly meta-information like class, types, names etc.?

Comment: Based on [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attributes.html), `Attributes of an object are not stored internally as a list and should be thought of as a set and not a vector`. Yeah, `attributes`  contains metadata of an object.